# Как убрать замену utf символов в JsonResponse?

Tags: python, django

Проблема в том, что возвращаются не сами символы, а их коды, например, строка 'кол' заменяется на '\u043a\u043e\u043b'. Python 3.4, django 1.8.5.
Вот код:

```
class HomePage(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        a = eval('{"кол": "2", "items": [{"id": "2", "body": "sad"}, {"id": "1", "body": "asdasad"}]}')
        return JsonResponse(a, content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8', safe=False)
```

Comment: `eval()` тут совершенно не к месту. Используйте просто `a = {"кол": "2", ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\u043a\u043e\u043b' == 'кол'` то есть с самой строкой ничего не надо делать.

Если ваше окружение может отображать русские буквы, то просто напечайте строку, чтобы убедиться:

```
print('\u043a\u043e\u043b')
# --> кол
```

Не нужно путать подобные строки с JSON строками, например: `'"\\u043a\\u043e"'`:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('"\\u043a\\u043e"') == json.loads('"\u043a\u043e"') == 'ко'
True
```

Если хочешь получить JSON строки с неэкранированными не-ascii символами, используй `ensure_ascii=False`:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({"кол": 2})
'{"\\u043a\\u043e\\u043b": 2}'
>>> json.dumps({"кол": 2}, ensure_ascii=False)
'{"кол": 2}'
```

Answer (score -1):

А зачем Вам убирать замену? На фронте обработайте ответ через     JSON.stringify('текст ответа') и вы получите свой "кол".

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?